# Creating Object[][] Types On The Fly

Tags: java, list, object

Here is my define class, I haven't included the getting code to keep it [short and sweet](http://sscce.org).

```
public class Details() {
  String name;
  double price;
  int quan;
  double totalValue;

  public String getName();
  public double getPrice();
  public int quan();
  public double totalValue();
}
```

This is how I hold my list of details

```
ArrayList<Details> myDetails = new ArrayList<Details>();
```

This is the function I would like to use to make my table rows/columns
Here I would like to be able to iterate though my details table to produce something similar to below.

```
public Object[][] getStockTable() {
  Object[][] dynamicObject = new Object[][] {
      { "Name1", "Price1", "Quan1", "TV1"  },
      { "Name2", "Price2", "Quan2", "TV2"  },
      { "Name3", "Price3", "Quan3", "TV3"  } };

  //But how do this by iterating through rather than manually like above^
  return dynamicObject;

}
```

This is how I'm setting the row/columns for the table

```
dm.setDataVector(getStockTable(), new Object[] { "Name","Price", "Quan", "Total Value" });
```

After some messing around I've not managed to come up with a way of doing this. Please don't just spoon feed me an answer, I would like to be able to understand how to do it rather than having it done for me.

Comment: You can use `Reflection` to determine fields and then create `Array`

Comment: Would you be able to give an example or link to a good tut?

Comment: no refletion needed, he can iterate over his list and create his arrays as needed using the getters.

Comment: Its actually making the arrays name,price,quan and total value into the correct Object[][] format as shown its confusing me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Object[][]` is simply an array of `Object[]`, so the OO way to do it would be to add a method to `Detail` that creates a single "row" `Object[]`

```
public Object[] toRow() {
  return new Object[] { getName(), String.valueOf(getPrice()) /* etc. */ };
}
```

then collect those up in `getStockTable`

```
Object[][] tbl = new Object[myDetails.size()][];
int row = 0;
for(Detail d : myDetails) {
  tbl[row++] = d.toRow();
}
```

Comment: Nice OO code, i dont understand how i didnt think ofthis. Great answer

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
public Object[][] getStockTable() {
    ArrayList<Details> details = getDatailsList();
    Object[][] result = new Object[details.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
        Details detail = details.get(i);
        Object[] det = new Object[4];
        det[0] = detail.getName();
        det[1] = detail.getPrice();
        det[2] = detail.quan();
        det[3] = detail.totalValue();
        result[i] = det;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, finally understand the logic required +1